# Derivation in the sense of distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $f_n(x)$ be a continuous sequence functions.
Assume that the series $\sum_{n\in N} f_n(x)$ converges simply.
Put $f(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0} f_n(x)$.
My question if the function $f$ is continuous.
Is that $$\big(\sum^\infty_{n=0} f_n(x)\big)'=\sum^\infty_{n=0} f'_n(x)$$
in the sense of distributions.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: No idea.  I think the result is true?

Comment: Equivalently, you have a sequence of continuous functions $F_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} f_k$ that converges pointwise. The question then is whether $\lim_{n\to\infty} F_n' = (\lim_{n\to\infty} F_n)'$ in the sense of distributions.

Comment: A first question is whether $F_n$ converges in the sense of distributions (to $F$ say). If it does, then the derivatives also converge since
$$
\langle F_n', \phi \rangle = - \langle F_n, \phi' \rangle \to - \langle F, \phi' \rangle = \langle F', \phi \rangle.
$$

Answer (score 2):

For $n=0, 1, 2, \ldots$ let $f_n = F_n - F_{n-1}$ where
$$
F_n(x) = \begin{cases}
n^2 x & \text{when $0 \leq x \leq 1/n$}, \\
n(2-nx) & \text{when $1/n \leq x \leq 2/n$}, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\sum_{k=0}^{n} f_k = F_n$ converges to $0$ pointwise but to $\delta$ as distribution. Therefore,
$$
0 = (\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k}_{\text{pointwise limit}})' \neq \underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k'}_{\text{distributional limit}} = \delta'.
$$

##### Pointwise convergence to $0$

For $x<0$ the "otherwise" case applies so $F_n(x)=0$ so here convergence to $0$ is trivial.

For $x=0$ the first case applies so $F_n(0)=n^2\cdot 0=0$ and convergence to $0$ is trivial.

For $x>0$ there exists some $n$ such that $x>2/n.$ The "otherwise" case then applies and convergence to $0$ is trivial.

Thus, $F_n \to 0$ pointwise.

##### Convergence to $\delta$

Let $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R).$ Then
$$
\langle F_n, \phi \rangle
\int F_n(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx
= \int_{0}^{1/n} n^2 x \, \phi(x) \, dx + \int_{1/n}^{2/n} n(2-nx) \, \phi(x) \, dx.
$$
Now change variable to $t=nx.$ This gives
$$
\langle F_n, \phi \rangle
= \int_{0}^{1} t \, \phi(t/n) \, dt + \int_{1}^{2} (2-t) \, \phi(t/n) \, dt
\to \int_{0}^{1} t \, \phi(0) \, dt + \int_{1}^{2} (2-t) \, \phi(0) \, dt
= \left( \int_{0}^{1} t \, dt + \int_{1}^{2} (2-t) \, dt \right) \, \phi(0)
= \phi(0)
= \langle \delta, \phi \rangle
$$
as $n\to\infty.$

This implies that $F_n'\to \delta'$ as distributions.

Comment: Thank you very much